# Opening one modal from another using the meteor way

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

How exactly do I open one modal from another modal in meteor? I'm using [bootstrap-3-modal package](https://github.com/PeppeL-G/bootstrap-3-modal)

When I try clicking on the `confirm` button of one modal, it must close that modal and open a new modal. Somehow,it doesn't seem to work. Here's what I have:

```
Template.addMoreTemplateConfirmationModal.events({
    'click #confirmMorePGInstance'(event){ // this is the confirm button on addMoreTemplateConfirmationModal modal 

        Modal.show('createTemplateModal'); // this does not work.
        // Modal.hide('addMoreTemplateConfirmationModal');

    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried closing the modal before showing the next one?

Otherwise you could maybe trigger the second modal on the `onDestroyed` event, although there might be a better way.

```
Template.addMoreTemplateConfirmationModal.onDestroyed(function() {
  Modal.show('createTemplateModal');
});
```

Comment: I tried closing the first before opening the second as well, but didn't work. I'll try your method today and get back here whether it works or not

Comment: Interestingly, When I call the modal in onDestroy, it just fails to render the modal. Anything else inside the onDestroy works.

Comment: Is there a way you can call the Modal.show() on the 'parent' page? That's usually what I do. The other thing you can do, although less elegant, is to use a timeout.

Comment: Meteor.show() on any other helper other than the current modal's helper works out fine. I'm trying to elemenate one modal leading to another altoghether due to lack of time right now. I'll check this out when I have more time on my hands

Comment: @blueren I want to see if you or anyone else has been able to resolve this issue. I am having a similar problem. I tested with a modal and an alert; the alert function worked but not the modal function. The modal function slightly grey's out the page but does not render. Here is the code just in case: Template.blogPost.onDestroyed(function () {
      // alert("STOP!");
      $('#signup-modal').modal('show');
  });

Comment: No. In the end I don't think I went with this approach. What you can actually do  as a workaround is - to open up multiple templates within the same modal instead of opening multiple modals. That way, modal stays, content within it changes based on activity you do

Comment: @blueren Thanks for the update. After doing some research I ended up using this package - https://github.com/PeppeL-G/bootstrap-3-modal. I hope this is useful for someone down the road who needs to create a call to action or pop-up using meteor onDestroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `setTimeout` which runs only once after given miliseconds (300 is the miliseconds in the example below).

```
'click #confirmMorePGInstance': function(){
    // close modal here
    Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
        //open the next modal here
    }, 300);
},
```

PS: I suggest using 50-100 miliseconds more than the closing effect speed.